# Terraform null_resources not showing output in Terraform 0.11

Tags: terraform

I am testing the below main.tf file content in terraform 0.11. I dont see any output printed in terraform apply.

```
locals {
    keys = ["rds.force_ssl", "ssl"]
    values = ["1", "2"]
}

resource "null_resource" "rds_dbparam_mapping" {
    count = "${length(local.keys)}"

    triggers {
        name = "${element(local.keys, count.index)}"
        value = "${element(local.values, count.index)}"
    }
}

output "rds_dbparams" {
    value = "${null_resource.rds_dbparam_mapping.*.triggers}"
}
```

The apply command just shows,

```
terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Even terraform validate is not printing any issues if I make syntax errors. Any help on this please?

Comment: AFAIK, it never does.

Comment: I even have problem with terraform init. Terraform init is not creating any .terraform folder. Doesnt seem to download the provider plugin. I tried adding
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 1.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
 region = "us-east-1"
 }

Comment: Actually in this page they have shared the output shown in terraform apply https://gist.github.com/brikis98/f3fe2ae06f996b40b55eebcb74ed9a9e

Answer (score 1):

I recommend updating your terraform to at least 0.14.0 since I've tested with all the versions from 11-14 & 14 is when I start seeing the outputs properly:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.rds_dbparam_mapping[0] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "rds_dbparam_mapping" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name"  = "rds.force_ssl"
          + "value" = "1"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.rds_dbparam_mapping[1] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "rds_dbparam_mapping" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "name"  = "ssl"
          + "value" = "2"
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + rds_dbparams = [
      + {
          + "name"  = "rds.force_ssl"
          + "value" = "1"
        },
      + {
          + "name"  = "ssl"
          + "value" = "2"
        },
    ]

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value:
```

Also the updated terraform syntax is easier to read:

```
locals {
    keys = ["rds.force_ssl", "ssl"]
    values = ["1", "2"]
}

resource "null_resource" "rds_dbparam_mapping" {
    count = length(local.keys)

    triggers = {
        name = element(local.keys, count.index)
        value = element(local.values, count.index)
    }
}

output "rds_dbparams" {
    value = null_resource.rds_dbparam_mapping.*.triggers
}
```

I use a tool called `tfenv` https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv to easily switch between versions